# How to plan messages on ejabberd?

Tags: erlang, ejabberd, ejabberd-hooks

I want to make my ejabberd able to plan messages.

Which could be the best solution for this purpose?

And supposing that I have all the messages stored on the db, with the recipient (to) and with the date (year, month, day, hour..) when they must be send.

Which could be the best option to handle it?

A cronjob at every minute that checks if there are messages to send? And in this case, how could it tells to the Ejabberd that it have to send the message?

Another option to handle it?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

develop your own  custom  ejabberd module using one of these  options - [timer](http://erlang.org/doc/man/timer.html#apply_interval-4):apply_interval/4 or timer:apply_after/4 or  implement built-in mechanism within [gen_server](http://erlang.org/doc/man/gen_server.html) to accomplish your task. Use *ejabberd_router:route(From, To, Stanza)* to send messages.

Comment: Thanks!! It could be a good choice using the 'mod_cron' module and implementing my own function that checks on database if there are pending messages?

Answer (score 1):

I would use the `send_message` API / Command from an external tool. That way you can do whatever you want in the programming language of your choice.

The `send_message` API is described here: https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/api/#sendmessage---send-a-message-to-a-local-or-remote-bare-of-full-jid